# Is it possible to run app in production mode in simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, cloudkit

I want to take screen shot about the app but when it runs in production mode and in simulator. Is it possible? Or do I have to build up the same dataset in development mode like in production mode?

Answer (score 8):

Goto Product >>> Edit scheme and then select as following:
[image]